# XCode does not open while its showing menu bar of XCode on top?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-monterey

When clicking on XCode, it moves and shows the menu options of XCode on the top.

I tried uninstalling and installing and system restart. Also I have tried some other options given in the menu bar, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What you mean by “while it’s showing menu bar of xcode”. And if you see this menu bar, does it work, or is it frozen? Is the question just “why do i not see ‘Welcome to Xcode’ window?” or is there something more serious going on? FWIW, if menu works and you’re just not seeing “Welcome to Xcode” window, if you manually go to “Window” » “Welcome to Xcode”, is the “Show this window when Xcode launches” box checked?

Comment: Is the question just “why do i not see ‘Welcome to Xcode’ window?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. As usual, looking forever results in no change but the instant I ask about it I find the solution almost immediately. For anyone having the same problem:

It is under the Window Menu 5th Item from the very bottom: WELCOME TO XCODE. There is also a keyboard shortcut associated with it, SHIFT+CMND+1

The culprit here is a tiny check box at the bottom of the window: SHOW THIS WINDOW WHEN XCODE LAUNCHES
Somehow that had become unchecked the last time I ran the program